# Creating an indicator variable in R

Tags: r, dataset

I'm new with R and working with the ALL dataset in R, and trying to create an indicator variable that defines =1 for all T-cell patients and =2 for all B-cell patients. Here is my code:

```
library(ALL)
data(ALL)
tcell<-c("T","T1","T2","T3","T4")
bcell<-c("B","B1","B2","B3","B4")
ALL.fac <- factor(ALL$BT, levels=1:2, labels=c(tcell,bcell))
ALL.fac
```

I'm getting an error which states:

> Error in factor(ALL$BT, levels = 1:2, labels = c(tcell, bcell)) : 
>     invalid 'labels'; length 10 should be 1 or 2

I'm not sure how to define the variable properly to get all the T-cells to print out as 1 and all B-cells to print as 2.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can remove the numeric part from the 'BT' using `sub` and then change the levels

```
All.fac <- factor(sub('\\d+', '', ALL$BT) ,
                levels=c('T', 'B'), labels=c(1,2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand what sub() does, but what does the '\\d+' mean in that code?

Comment: @Jay We are matching one or more numbers (`\\d+`) in the string and replace it with `''` so that only `T` or `B` remains.